# Mock the function call of a mocked object in Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

In my component, we call a third party API. It would call
`ThirdPartyApi.card.createNewCard` and `ThirdPartyApi.setKey`

What I did in my unit test is I created a spy object for `card` but could not figure out how to create a spy for the function `createNewCard`

This is what I did but it is wrong:

```
const createNewCard = jasmine.createSpy('createNewCard');
window['ThirdPartyApi'] =  jasmine.createSpyObj([createNewCard, 'setKey']);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any errors? What do you expect?

Comment: Hi sir. the error is `Cannot read property 'createNewCard' of undefined when calling 
`ThirdPartyApi.card.createNewCard`. the `card` part is not properly mocked but I don't know how.>_<

Answer (score 0):

This should be

````
window['ThirdPartyApi'] =  jasmine.createSpyObj(['card', 'setKey']);
ThirdPartyApi.card = jasmine.createSpyObj(['createNewCard']);```
````